# How to apply tz_convert with different timezones to different rows in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, python-datetime

I am trying to set different timezones for various rows in a Pandas dataframe based on a criterion. As a MWE, here is what I have tried:

```
test = pd.DataFrame( data = pd.to_datetime(['2015-03-30 20:12:32','2015-03-12 00:11:11']) ,columns=['time'] )
test['new_col']=['new','old']
test.time=test.set_index('time').index.tz_localize('UTC')
test.loc[test.new_col=='new','time']=test[test.new_col=='new'].set_index('time').index.tz_convert('US/Pacific')
print test
```

The output of this:

```
                        time new_col
0        1427746352000000000     new
1  2015-03-12 00:11:11+00:00     old
```

As you can see, the row with the updated timezone is converted to an integer. How can I do this properly so that the updated entry is a datetime?

Comment: It is not possible to have different timezones in one column (columns are homogeneous typed)

Comment: This doesn't seem to be true, see the example below.

Comment: Yes, but as @jreback explained, then you don't have a datetime column anymore, but an object columns (which can contain in principle anythin), losing much of the useful functionality

Answer (score 1):

Using 0.17.0rc2 (0.17.0 is release on Oct 9), you *can* do this.

```
In [43]: test['new_col2'] = [Timestamp('2015-03-30 20:12:32',tz='US/Eastern'),Timestamp('2015-03-30 20:12:32',tz='US/Pacific')]

In [44]: test
Out[44]: 
                       time new_col                   new_col2
0 2015-03-30 20:12:32+00:00     new  2015-03-30 20:12:32-04:00
1 2015-03-12 00:11:11+00:00     old  2015-03-30 20:12:32-07:00

In [45]: test.dtypes
Out[45]: 
time        datetime64[ns, UTC]
new_col                  object
new_col2                 object
dtype: object
```

Note that *mixed* timezones *within* a column with force `object` dtype. So it can be done, but is generally not recommended. You would need to change entries individually.

You almost always a single dtyped column of a single timezone.

Comment: I had missed that Pandas is converting the mixed timezone column to dtype `object`. However, when I set the time as the index (e.g. `test[test.new_col=='new'].set_index('time').index`) I do in fact get a DatetimeIndex. But, when I try to assign it back to the original column it turns into gibberish. Can you explain why I should expect that behavior?

Comment: in 0.16.2 this is a bug, in 0.17.0 this will raise , see [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/11259)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that works once you add a column that specifies the timezone to convert to.

```
utc_df = pd.DataFrame({"timestamp": [pd.Timestamp("2019-09-01 12:00:00+0000", tz="UTC"),
                                     pd.Timestamp("2019-11-01 12:00:00+0000", tz="UTC")],
                        "timezone": ["Europe/Brussels", "Europe/London"]})
```

This sample still has the time in UTC and looks like:

```
                  timestamp         timezone 
0 2019-09-01 12:00:00+00:00  Europe/Brussels 
1 2019-11-01 12:00:00+00:00    Europe/London
```

We then group by timezone and apply the conversion.

```
def localize_time(df):
    def convert_tz(tz_df):
        return tz_df.set_index('timestamp').tz_convert(tz_df.timezone.values[0]).reset_index()

    return df.groupby('timezone').apply(convert_tz).reset_index(drop=True)

localize_time(utc_df)
```

Which returns:

```
                   timestamp         timezone
0  2019-09-01 14:00:00+02:00  Europe/Brussels
1  2019-11-01 12:00:00+00:00    Europe/London
```

**Do note** the `dtype` of timestamp column will change to `object`.

```
utc_df.dtypes
timestamp    datetime64[ns, UTC]
timezone                  object

localize_time(utc_df).dtypes
timestamp    object
timezone     object
```

However, you can still access the datetime functionality of this column as long as you keep grouping by timezone and then apply the function you want to (like in the example shown here).