# Construct column with Heterogeneous Timezones in Dataframe and localize it

Tags: datetime, pandas, dataframe, timezone, pytz

**Problem:** 
I am trying to create a DateTime column using date, time and timezone columns. The TimeZones are heterogeneous. Subsequently convert time in newly created DateTime column to local TimeZone. Below I have explained my use-case with sample code.

**Use-case and Sample code:**
I have two pandas DataFrames, viz., `df1` and `df2`.
 `df1` has open/close time in local TimeZone for schools in different countries with their respective TimeZones provided.

```
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame({'School': {0: 'ABC', 2: 'GHI', 3: 'JKL', 4: 'MNO'}, 'OpenTime': {0: '08:00:00.000', 2: '10:00:23.563', 3: '09:30.05.908', 4: '07:15:50.100'}, 'CloseTime': {0: '13:00:00.000', 2: '13:30:00.100', 3: '15:00.00.768', 4: '13:00:00.500'}, 'TimeZone':{0:'Europe/Vienna', 2:'Europe/London', 3:'Pacific/Auckland', 4:'Asia/Seoul'}})
>>> df1
      CloseTime      OpenTime School          TimeZone
0  13:00:00.000  08:00:00.000    ABC     Europe/Vienna
2  13:30:00.100  10:00:23.563    GHI     Europe/London
3  15:00.00.768  09:30.05.908    JKL  Pacific/Auckland
4  13:00:00.500  07:15:50.100    MNO        Asia/Seoul
```

`df2` is just an intermediate DataFrame with bunch of dates.

```
 >>> df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Dates': {0: '2016-11-02', 1: '2015-03-31', 2: '2015-10-30', 3: '2001-09-01'}})
>>> df2
        Dates
0  2016-11-02
1  2015-03-31
2  2015-10-30
3  2001-09-01
```

`df3` is just a Cartesian product of `df1` and `df2`, as follows:

```
>>> df1['key'], df2['key'] =0,0
>>> df3 = df1.merge(df2, how='left', on='key')
>>> df3
       CloseTime      OpenTime School          TimeZone  key       Dates
0   13:00:00.000  08:00:00.000    ABC     Europe/Vienna    0  2016-11-02
1   13:00:00.000  08:00:00.000    ABC     Europe/Vienna    0  2016-05-02
2   13:00:00.000  08:00:00.000    ABC     Europe/Vienna    0  2015-03-31
...
```

Now I am trying to figure out best way to perform following two steps on `df3`:
1) Convert `OpenTime` and `CloseTime` columns to DateTime  using `Dates` and `TimeZone` info.
2) Convert `OpenTime` and `CloseTime` to 'Europe/London' TimeZone.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need first [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) and then `apply` for convert to different timezones. Last use [`tz_localize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.tz_localize.html) for reset to `UTC` first and then localize to `Europe/London`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'School': {0: 'ABC', 2: 'GHI', 3: 'JKL', 4: 'MNO'}, 'OpenTime': {0: '08:00:00.000', 2: '10:00:23.563', 3: '09:30:05.908', 4: '07:15:50.100'}, 'CloseTime': {0: '13:00:00.000', 2: '13:30:00.100', 3: '15:00:00.768', 4: '13:00:00.500'}, 'TimeZone':{0:'Europe/Vienna', 2:'Europe/London', 3:'Pacific/Auckland', 4:'Asia/Seoul'}})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Dates': {0: '2016-11-02', 1: '2015-03-31', 2: '2015-10-30', 3: '2001-09-01'}})

df1['key'], df2['key'] = 0,0
df3 = df1.merge(df2, how='left', on='key')
print (df3)

df3['Close'] = pd.to_datetime(df3.Dates +' '+ df3.CloseTime) 
df3['Open'] = pd.to_datetime(df3.Dates +' '+ df3.OpenTime) 
df3['CloseFin'] = df3.apply(lambda x: x.Close.tz_localize(x.TimeZone), axis=1)
df3['OpenFin'] = df3.apply(lambda x: x.Open.tz_localize(x.TimeZone), axis=1)


df3['OpenEULondon'] = df3['Open'].dt.tz_localize('UTC').dt.tz_convert('Europe/London')
df3['CloseEULondon'] = df3['Close'].dt.tz_localize('UTC').dt.tz_convert('Europe/London')
```

```
print (df3) 
...
...
                            CloseFin                           OpenFin  \
0          2016-11-02 13:00:00+01:00         2016-11-02 08:00:00+01:00   
1          2015-03-31 13:00:00+02:00         2015-03-31 08:00:00+02:00   
2          2015-10-30 13:00:00+01:00         2015-10-30 08:00:00+01:00   
3          2001-09-01 13:00:00+02:00         2001-09-01 08:00:00+02:00   
4   2016-11-02 13:30:00.100000+00:00  2016-11-02 10:00:23.563000+00:00   
5   2015-03-31 13:30:00.100000+01:00  2015-03-31 10:00:23.563000+01:00   
6   2015-10-30 13:30:00.100000+00:00  2015-10-30 10:00:23.563000+00:00   
7   2001-09-01 13:30:00.100000+01:00  2001-09-01 10:00:23.563000+01:00   
8   2016-11-02 15:00:00.768000+13:00  2016-11-02 09:30:05.908000+13:00   
9   2015-03-31 15:00:00.768000+13:00  2015-03-31 09:30:05.908000+13:00   
10  2015-10-30 15:00:00.768000+13:00  2015-10-30 09:30:05.908000+13:00   
11  2001-09-01 15:00:00.768000+12:00  2001-09-01 09:30:05.908000+12:00   
12  2016-11-02 13:00:00.500000+09:00  2016-11-02 07:15:50.100000+09:00   
13  2015-03-31 13:00:00.500000+09:00  2015-03-31 07:15:50.100000+09:00   
14  2015-10-30 13:00:00.500000+09:00  2015-10-30 07:15:50.100000+09:00   
15  2001-09-01 13:00:00.500000+09:00  2001-09-01 07:15:50.100000+09:00   

                       OpenEULondon                    CloseEULondon  
0         2016-11-02 08:00:00+00:00        2016-11-02 13:00:00+00:00  
1         2015-03-31 09:00:00+01:00        2015-03-31 14:00:00+01:00  
2         2015-10-30 08:00:00+00:00        2015-10-30 13:00:00+00:00  
3         2001-09-01 09:00:00+01:00        2001-09-01 14:00:00+01:00  
4  2016-11-02 10:00:23.563000+00:00 2016-11-02 13:30:00.100000+00:00  
5  2015-03-31 11:00:23.563000+01:00 2015-03-31 14:30:00.100000+01:00  
6  2015-10-30 10:00:23.563000+00:00 2015-10-30 13:30:00.100000+00:00  
7  2001-09-01 11:00:23.563000+01:00 2001-09-01 14:30:00.100000+01:00  
8  2016-11-02 09:30:05.908000+00:00 2016-11-02 15:00:00.768000+00:00  
9  2015-03-31 10:30:05.908000+01:00 2015-03-31 16:00:00.768000+01:00  
10 2015-10-30 09:30:05.908000+00:00 2015-10-30 15:00:00.768000+00:00  
11 2001-09-01 10:30:05.908000+01:00 2001-09-01 16:00:00.768000+01:00  
12 2016-11-02 07:15:50.100000+00:00 2016-11-02 13:00:00.500000+00:00  
13 2015-03-31 08:15:50.100000+01:00 2015-03-31 14:00:00.500000+01:00  
14 2015-10-30 07:15:50.100000+00:00 2015-10-30 13:00:00.500000+00:00  
15 2001-09-01 08:15:50.100000+01:00 2001-09-01 14:00:00.500000+01:00
```

But `dtypes` of column `CloseFin` and `OpenFin` is `object`, [see](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32990668/2901002):

```
print (df3.dtypes)
CloseTime                               object
OpenTime                                object
School                                  object
TimeZone                                object
key                                      int64
Dates                                   object
Close                           datetime64[ns]
Open                            datetime64[ns]
CloseFin                                object
OpenFin                                 object
OpenEULondon     datetime64[ns, Europe/London]
CloseEULondon    datetime64[ns, Europe/London]
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. However I am getting following at line `df3.apply(lambda x: pd.Timestamp(x.Close...` :      .                         .`File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>`
  `File "pandas/tslib.pyx", line 278, in pandas.tslib.Timestamp.__new__ (pandas/tslib.c:7638)`
  `File "pandas/tslib.pyx", line 1114, in pandas.tslib.convert_to_tsobject (pandas/tslib.c:20277)`
`ValueError: occurred at index 12`

Comment: What is youir pandas version? `print (pd.show_versions)` Error is with your samples?

Comment: 0.16.2. No I just ran the same sample as I provided above.

Comment: I think there is problem with your pandas version. Last is `0.19.1` and then it works perfectly.

Comment: I am not surprised but upgrading version is difficult as legacy code depend on earlier versions and future versions are not backward compatible.

Comment: Code run without error. However results are not quite what I expected. DST is not handled properly. For example, compare `OpenTime` and `OpenEULondon` columns of final `df3` for index 0 and 1. I expect these rows to show same time for each field respectively. 8AM in Vienna on 2-Nov and 31-Mar is always 9AM in London. However row 0 shows 8AM London. The whole idea of this exercise is to handle idiosyncrasies of Day Light Saving time across the globe seamlessly.

Comment: Sorry, now I hahe no idea for this problem. Maybe this is bug, i am not sure.